# LIbrary issue: How do I set up QtWebKit to parse HTML?

Tags: html, qt, html-parsing, qtwebkit, qwebelement

Nick Presta showed that you can parse HTML with qt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

However, when I attempt to build this, I get an access violation on the "QWebFrame* frame = page.mainFrame();" line.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <QtWebKit\QWebElement>
#include <QtWebKit\QWebView>
#include <QtWebKit\QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKit\QWebPage>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 QWebPage page;
 QWebFrame* frame = page.mainFrame();

 frame->setHtml( "<html><head></head><body></body></html>" );
 QWebElement document = frame->documentElement();

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You often need a `QApplication` (for GUI, for others, use `QCoreApplicaiton`) object before you do anything useful in Qt.

Try declaring one at the top of main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ...

    return a.exec(); // start event handling (if you have some UI or networking that is event based)
}
```

Returning `a.exec()` instead of `0` (as my original code was before edit) is fine **if** you have event handling. If you just want to parse a document and work with it, you might not don't need an event loop.

OTOH, WebKit is async so running the exec loop and waiting for results is not a bad idea per se, just not required.

Comment: Anything that involves `QtGui` needs `QApplication` , for others you need `QCoreApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the Qt example like previewer something like the code as follows:

```
QString text = plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
webView->setHtml(text, baseUrl);
```